# Check if gl context was destroyed

Tags: android, opengl-es, openglcontext

Is there way to detect if opengl context was disposed when user has pressed `home` button?Currently I always recreate whole glSurface in `onResume` method.Also there is `setPreserveEGLContextOnPause` which might keep context alive.I'd like to use it to not recreate glSurface each time.The question is how to detect if I need to recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `eglGetCurrentContext()` returns `EGL_NO_CONTEXT`.

> I'd like to use it to not recreate glSurface each time

Note this is bad practise - it means that your process hogs more memory when it's not in use. In many cases this just means Android will simply kill your process completely if the foreground process needs more memory.

Comment: What scope this method belongs to?I've checked GLES20 and GLSurfaceView its not there.Anyway I solved problem with ready flag which is set within onSurfaceCreated if this method called twice - I release all resources and recreate everything from scratch.

Comment: android.opengl.EGL14; EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();

Comment: Thanks but this  feature requires api level 17 while we're targeted on 16.So I'd stay on my current solution.